# Isn't the equation for power more complicated?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, work, power

I’ve been told that work is equal to $Fs$ and power is work done  per second $dW/dt$ so looking at the equation, isn't power more like this? $\frac{dF}{dt}s + F\frac{ds}{dt}$

Edit: Now that I'm not in high school, I've learned that work is not $Fs$, it's $\int F \,\mathrm{d}s$, a line integral, apparently. Making it's derivative somewhat more nuanced, I'll add a bit more after I know a bit more vector calculus

Comment: I assume this question arises because your book exhibits an equation something like $P = F v$ somwhere, yes? I find that most intro books are not particualrly clear about this point. They general *do* state the constraints that lead to that expression, but readers nearly universally overlook them. As you note, that is *not* a general expression, but rather one that applies to a particular and limited class of problems.

Comment: @dmckee spot on, do you mind explaining the constraint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression
$$ P = F v \;, $$
is usually used in the context of questions like

> *"How much power does the engine need to be able to provide to maintain the vehicle at a constant speed $v$ if the resistive forces have total magnitude $F$?"*.

In that case you can say, that the engine must supply a force of magnitude $F$ to establish equilibrium and the power of the engine is:
$$ P = \frac{W}{\Delta t} = \frac{F \, \Delta x}{\Delta t} = F \frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t} = F v \;.$$
And in that context your objection (which is of course generally correct) is a non-issue because $\frac{\mathrm{d}F}{\mathrm{d}t} = 0$.

There are two things that are going on here.

1. We have chosen a particular force/energy source to evaluate. Notice that the work-energy theorem tells us that the *net* work done is zero (because we have assumed constant speed), so we *must* be looking at a selected subset.<sup>1</sup>
2. Because we are assuming a steady state situation we can interchange average and instantaneous quantities with impunity.

So, if it applies to such a tightly defined condition what use is this expression and why bother to tabulate it in a chapter that mostly contains very broadly applicable principles? Good question. If you know (are given/can guess/have measured) how the resistive forces depend on velocity then you can find

- The maximum sustainable speed given maximum power (or a power-curve in the case of, for example, geared internal combustion vehicles)
- "Gas mileage" or other measures of efficiency.

both of which are interesting from a day-to-day perspective as well as from an engineering perspective.

---

<sup>1</sup> Neglecting to state *what* work is being considered is one of the most common oversights I see in talking about energy/work/power. By students, sure, but also by textbook authors and other who really should know better.

Answer (score 1):

Your definition for Power is correct, however, it is more intuitive to think of it as *amount of energy transferred per unit time*. Now, since the energy transferred per unit time is just the work done, i.e. $$ dW = \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{s}$$ Here, you have to understand a very essential point, when we wrote $\mathbf {F} \cdot d\mathbf{s}$ we considered that $\mathbf{F}$ was constant through the displacement $d\mathbf{s}$. Therefore, energy transferred per unit time in moving a object through distance of $ds$ with a force $F$ is $$ P = \frac{dW}{dt}$$
Considering, the force and displacement to be in same direction  we have
$$ P = \frac{F~ds}{dt}$$
$$P = F \frac{ds}{dt} \implies P = F~v$$
Now, let's understand this formula a little, we said that our force caused a displacement $ds$, but we should say that force at $t$ caused a displacement $ds$ and if write the force at $t$ as $F(t)$ and surely $ds/dt$ can be written as $v(t)$ (this only means that what was the velocity when the force acted at time $t$) and therefore we can write Power at time $t$ (energy transferred in unit time at time $t$) as $$ P(t) = F(t) ~v(t)$$ The intuition that Power depends on velocity is that whenever we apply a force on an object it's velocity will change, more the velocity change (more the change in Kinetic Energy, $ W = \Delta KE = 1/2 m (v_2^2-v_1^2)$ ) means more energy has been transferred and hence, more the Power.